# I'm unable to open Steam on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: steam

I was able to play Dota 2 on Ubuntu 16.04. Then I tried to install graphics driver (amdgpu-pro) and fglrx on my OS. After that I messed up with my Steam.

So, today I upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.10 so that I can run the Steam, but it is still not working. The same error is going on.

It stucks at:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
```

Comment: Cristiana do you have any solutions?